# LSTM Keras confusion

Tags: python, numpy, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

@enumaris thank you for your answer. I'll try to explain my approach a bit:

I pushed the video frames through resnet model and got fature shapes of `(k, 2048)`. I have the data into train/validation and test folders. Then I was writing this script:

```py
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.layers import Activation, Dropout, Dense

import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import argparse
import random
import cv2
import os


dataTrain  = []
labelsTrain = []


# Prepare the Training Data. The .txt files contain name of the name of the 
#file and the label which is 0,1,or 2 based on which class the video belongs
#to (nameVideo.npy 0)
with open('D:...\Data\/train_files.txt') as f:
    trainingList = f.readlines()
    for line in trainingList:
        npyFiles = line.split( )
        loadTrainingData = np.load(npyFiles[0])
        dataTrain.append(loadTrainingData)
        labelsTrain.append(npyFiles[1])
        dataNp = np.array(dataTrain, dtype=object)
        labelsNp = np.array(labelsTrain, dtype=object)
        f.close()

dataVal  = []
labelsVal = []

# Prepare the Validation Data
with open('D:\...\Data\/val_files.txt') as f:
    valList = f.readlines()
    for line in valList:
        npyValFiles = line.split( )
        loadValData = np.load(npyValFiles[0])
        dataVal.append(loadValData)
        labelsVal.append(npyValFiles[1])
        f.close()

print(len(dataVal))

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(32,
               batch_input_shape=(None, None, 1),
               return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(32, return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(32))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='mean_absolute_error',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()

history = model.fit(dataTrain, labelsTrain,
                    epochs=10,
                    validation_data=(dataVal, labelsVal))
```

Which results in the following error:

> ValueError: Error when checking model input: the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected. Expected to see 1 array(s), but instead got the following list of 3521 arrays.

Comment: It's pretty hard to debug code if you don't actually show the code and the full stack trace. It looks like you are inputting a list of a bunch of arrays instead of a single array as your input. But it's hard to tell. Keras LSTM will expect your input to be an array of shape (batch_size,time_steps,num_features).

Comment: @enumaris thank you for your answer. I'll try to explain my approach a bit: basically I pushed the video frames through resnet model and got fature shapes of k x 2048 . I have the data into train/validation and test folders.

Comment: What is the problem? You just introduced what you have done so far. On a side note: it's very uncommon to train a model with a `softmax` activation and `mse` loss -- `categorical_crossentropy` is probably a better fit.

Comment: @ldavid I am getting the error above. I changed the loss function as suggested. Thank you!

Comment: Then I'm fairly confident @enumaris comment is correct. Have you tried it?